# Array to string conversion in error using smarty

Tags: php, arrays, string, smarty

I'm trying to print an array on smarty template which I made on php. And I get this error :

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\smarty\templates_c\e43b807af9cc8df7d350c3baf9e47f167c9520a0.file.index.tpl.php on line 87

I couldn't figure how to solve it. Can you tell me where is the error?

Here is the part where I make the array in php

```
function get_db_results()
{
    $mysql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question";
    $myresult = mysql_query($mysql);
    $myr = mysql_fetch_row($myresult);
    SmartyPaginate::setTotal($myr[0]);
    $index = SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex();
    $limit =SmartyPaginate::getLimit();
    $rsql = "SELECT question_title FROM question ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT $index, $limit ";

    $rresult = mysql_query($rsql);
    //$column = array();

    while($rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rresult , MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $column[]=$rrow;

    }


    return $column;
}
$smarty->assign('results', get_db_results());
```

And here is the smart part :

```
{section name=res loop=$results}
    {$results[res]}
{/section}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `{$results[res]}` to `{$results.res}` Assuming you have key "res" in your array

By looking at your function I guess it should be :

```
{$results.question_title}
```

Here is the solution :

```
{foreach from=$results item=results name=results}
    {$results.question_title}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: At this time I got this : Undefined index: question_title in C:\wamp\www\smarty\templates_

Comment: can you add your `get_db_results()` functions out put, i can explain based on that

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\smarty\myindex.php on line 57 -- Line 57 is : echo get_db_results(); -- Thanks

Comment: Try this : `echo "<pre>";print_r(get_db_results());`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => who is this? 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => soru 23823
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => Deneme 1-2?
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => Yeni görünüm?
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => which flower?
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => what is this?
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [question_title] => saat şimdi?
        )

   .....

Comment: @user1954132 {$results[res].question_title} defined by me.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin sorry, I didn't see you wrote it. Thank you too!

Comment: @AdvaitAmin I am so sorry if I offended you really. I figured out the solution of the problem myself after outputting the function which Mr. Bendra gave. I didn't see your answer first. I'm really sorry, I didn't want to be rude to you. Your answer was really helpful too. Thank you.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin I tried to do at the first place already but it says I don't have enough reputation to upvote. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

First **delete** all cache file from `C:\wamp\www\smarty\templates_c\`, after that try like this `{$results[res].YOUR FIELD NAME}` because you used `{section}{/section}`.

**e.g.** `{$results[res].question_title}`

Hope help you.

Comment: This time I get this : ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: res in C:\wamp\www\smarty\templates_c\e43b807af9cc8df7d350c3baf9e47f167c9520a0.file.index.tpl.php on line 87

Comment: First print get_db_results(), in that you get the data?

Comment: @AdvaitAmin : +1 for your answer.